# Vagrant box and Docker provider: Titan and Kafka

Tags: docker, vagrant, apache-kafka, titan

I have been recently introduced to the notion of Docker containers and found myself looking for one that runs Titan together with Kafka. I do not seem to be able to find what I need in Docker Hub and I wonder whether there is a viable option to have a Vagrant box (VirtualBox) where Kafka has been installed manually (according to the installation steps) and a Docker image for Titan (https://hub.docker.com/r/elubow/titan-gremlin/) stood up from the VagrantFile configurations. What is your view? Are there better options out there? My ultimate scope is to write into Titan a number of sample messages consumed by a sample Kafka Consumer. Is this a reasonable set up for experimenting with it?

Thank you,

Regards,

Ilaria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this in full Docker. You should have a look at this [kafka-docker](https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker) project on GitHub. It use the [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) approach, which aim is to run different dependant services in distinct containers.

Using the `docker-compose.yml` file at the root of this kafka-docker project, you can imagine something like this for your use case:

```
zookeeper:
  image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
  ports: 
    - "2181"
kafka:
  build: .
  ports:
    - "9092"
  links: 
    - zookeeper:zk
  environment:
    KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 192.168.59.103
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
titan:
  image: <your titan image name>
  ports: <your titan port>
  links:
    - kafka
    - zookeeper:zk
```

This will run 3 distinct services in 3 distinct containers:

- one zookeeper on port `2181`
- one kafka, built with `Dockerfile` at the root of the repo on port `9002`
- your titan container

The interresting stuff here is `links:` this will create network links between your container. Here inside the titan container, kafka will be reachable at `kafka:9002`.

You should play with all this to have your fully Docker based kafka + titan

Comment: This is brilliant, thanks. It is really what I was looking for.